# MySQL query which will let me show the author of the list as well in my html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Ok here is my problem, I was trying to test user authentication on web pages (registration and login), and that was successful, a user signs in and enter a thing/topic which then is displayed on html page, two tables involved. one user with three columns (id, username, password) 2nd "list" with 7 columns (id, time, time_eidited) etc..  it looks like below image.[image: home page]
now what i want is to show another column in the web table which shows the user name who entered that post/topic.. Like if I (Hassan) enter a topic let say war i want it to show my name too at the end in a column named as "author". i've been thinking but it ain't coming to me that how i'm supposed to accomplish this. whether to make a column in "list" table or what??? any help will be greatly appreciated.

ok here is the page code:

***home.php***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first PHP website</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start(); //starts the session
if($_SESSION['user']){ //checks if user is logged in
}
else{
    header("location:index.php"); // redirects if user is not logged in
}
$user = $_SESSION['user']; //assigns user value
?>
<body>
    <h2>Home Page</h2>
    <p>Hello <?php Print "$user"?>!</p> <!--Displays user's name-->
    <a href="logout.php">Click here to logout</a><br/><br/>
    <form action="add.php" method="POST">
        Add more to list: <input type="text" name="details"/><br/>
        public post? <input type="checkbox" name="public[]" value="yes"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to list"/>
    </form>
    <h2 align="center">My list</h2>
    <table border="1px" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Post Time</th>
            <th>Edit Time</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Public Post</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
            mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //connect to database
            $query = mysql_query("Select * from list"); // SQL Query
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                Print "<tr>";
                    Print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
                    Print '<td align="center">'. $row['details'] . "</td>";
                    Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_posted']. " - ". $row['time_posted']."</td>";
                    Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_edited']. " - ". $row['time_edited']. "</td>";
                    Print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">edit</a> </td>';
                    Print '<td align="center"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('.$row['id'].')">delete</a> </td>';
                    Print '<td align="center">'. $row['public']. "</td>";
                Print "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <script>
        function myFunction(id)
        {
        var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        if (r==true)
          {
            window.location.assign("delete.php?id=" + id);
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

***add.php***

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']){
}
else{
    header("location:index.php");
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST") //Added an if to keep the page secured
{
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $time = strftime("%X");//time
    $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");//date
    $decision ="no";

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    foreach($_POST['public'] as $each_check) //gets the data from the checkbox
    {
        if($each_check !=null ){ //checks if the checkbox is checked
            $decision = "yes"; //sets teh value
        }
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (details, date_posted, time_posted, public) VALUES ('$details','$date','$time','$decision')"); //SQL query
    header("location: home.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:home.php"); //redirects back to hom
}
```

?>

Comment: you can add one more column in the table "list" called "author" and when ever you are adding a new row to the list add user name who is logged in to the site by default to the "author" column.

Comment: there arise the problem again , ok i create another column "author" in the list table then how "add" button will enter the user name in author column. i mean how will it get to know who is entering the topic

Comment: can you show your add.php code. so that i can help you.

Comment: ok code added above in question

Comment: you did not get me. show me that code which execute when you click on "Add to List" button. i.e code in "add.php" file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you "List" table add one more column called "author" and use the below code: 
here i am taking the author name from session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']){
}
else{
    header("location:index.php");
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST") //Added an if to keep the page secured
{
    $author=$_SESSION['user'];// here you are getting the author . as the person who is logged will add a row to the list
    $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $time = strftime("%X");//time
    $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");//date
    $decision ="no";

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database
    foreach($_POST['public'] as $each_check) //gets the data from the checkbox
    {
        if($each_check !=null ){ //checks if the checkbox is checked
            $decision = "yes"; //sets teh value
        }
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO list (details, date_posted, time_posted, public,author) VALUES ('$details','$date','$time','$decision','$author')"); //SQL query
    header("location: home.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:home.php"); //redirects back to hom
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks brother... it solved my problem :) :) thank you

Comment: please accept this answer if you think it solved your problem :)

Comment: sorry you din not ... :) click on the accept answer

Comment: i don't see "accept" button anywhere o.O can you please guide me where it is?

Comment: figured it out :) :D :P

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create new sql table. Let's say **visits(log_ID, username, post_ID, time, date**). Do not overload list table. *post_ID* should be equal to the *id* from the list table.

Create php function that INSERTs into *visits* table:

```
$username=$_SESSION['user'];// visitors name
$time = strftime("%X");//time
$date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");//date
$post_ID // need to see your code to get idea how to retrieve that ID

mysql_query("INSERT INTO visits (log_ID, username, post_ID, time, date) (NULL,'$username','$post_ID','$time','$date')"); //SQL query
```

That function must be called each time post is visited.

Comment: can you explain a bit more please, ok i create a new table as you said , but i'm new to php and mysql so if it was paper work then i know that how to enter a foreign key but i've to do it in phpmyadmin so tell me how do i do that it works

Comment: @HassanZia I would not suggest you to use foreign key. Also, add ID as a first column in your list table. Tick it as auto increment. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html